# input type email allows everything

Tags: html

I'm trying to add an email input to my form in HTML5, but somehow it still allows me to write anything without @ and the other stuff that an email contains.

```
 <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
```

Also tried:

```
<input type="text" pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
```

and still nothing happens if I write it incorrectly.

Comment: What do you expect to receive? It only validates after you submit a form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect the error message in the input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496266/detect-the-error-message-in-the-input-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not trying to validate while typing, then it will automatically show error after you submit it.

Comment: It does not show any errors. It just simply send the email with the invalid email.